# Python Encode Ã3 as ó

Tags: python, decode, encode

I have a string like

> '**La empresa de capitales mixtos que opera el predio de residuos,
>   Ceamse, aclarÃ3 este martes que la responsabilidad del
>   desentendimiento con los recicladores informales que provocÃ3 un
>   nuevo bloqueo y hace peligrar la recolecciÃ3n**'

and y need this

> '**La empresa de capitales mixtos que opera el predio de residuos,
>   Ceamse, aclaró este martes que la responsabilidad del
>   desentendimiento con los recicladores informales que provocó un
>   nuevo bloqueo y hace peligrar la recolección**'

how can I do this with Python ?

thanks!

Comment: How did you create the string, and how are you displaying it? Do you understand what Unicode is? Do you understand what a text encoding is?

Comment: Are you using Python 3, and this is an actual Unicode `str` and not `bytes`? If so then things might be a little trickier as the data is essentially corrupted. If the string in question is stored in variable x, what does it say when you `print repr(x)`?

Comment: This is straightforward mojibake, The `'ó'` was encoded in UTF-8 but decoded using Latin-1 to get `'Ã³'`.

Comment: I have scraped that string from a website

Comment: This might come handy: https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

Comment: Fix your webscraping script!

Comment: @PrestonLanders when I print the string the result is the same, and idem when I write a .txt

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your webscraping script!

It looks like La Capital sends proper http header and html head information, and the content is UTF-8 encoded. So your script needs to handle that, and everything will work fine.

I know from experience requests.get and beautifulsoup 4 both handles Unicode well, so just debug your script, and see where it goes wrong. Check the raw input, check if you need your page's .content or .text, and fix it accordingly.

Comment: thank you! I solved writing 
response = request.get(link)
html = response.text.encode('ISO-8859-1', 'ignore')

which is the encoding when I ask 

response.encoding